# Number of $n$-uples with a fixed infinite norm

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following question. Fix an integer $k$.

We wonder how many $n$-uples $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ are in $\mathbf{N}^n$ such that $\displaystyle\max_{i = 1, .., n}x_i = k$.

Comment: I don't know any of the technical jargons, but is your question equivalent to counting the number of $n$-tuples $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ such that $\max(x_i) = k$?

Comment: I've just edited the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 3):

If my limited understanding of your technical jargons is correct, you want to count the number of $n$-tuples $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ such that $\max(x_i) = k$.

Instead, first consider the number of tuples where $\max(x_i)\leq k$. This means *each* $x_i \leq k$, so there are $k^n$ such tuples.

Now, $|\{\max(x_i) = k\}| = |\{\max(x_i) \leq k\}| - |\{\max(x_i) \leq k - 1\}| = k^n - k^{n - 1}$.

Hope this helps!

---

Here's an alternative solution which is more clumsy: We consider where the first occurrence of $k$ is.

- If $x_1 = k$, then it doesn't matter (well, $\leq k$) what $x_i$ is for $i\geq 2$, so there is $k^{n - 1}$ cases.
- If $x_2 = k$, then we want $x_1 < k$ to avoid overcounting, and so there are $k^{n - 2}(k - 1)$ cases.
- $\ldots$
- If $x_i = k$, then we want $x_j < k$ for $j < i$, so there are $k^{n - i}(k - 1)^{i - 1}$ cases.

Summing it up, we have $\sum_{i=1}^n k^{n - i}(k - 1)^{i - 1} = \frac{\frac{k^{n + 1} - (k - 1)^{n + 1}}{k - (k - 1)} - k^n}{k - 1} = \frac{k^n(k - 1) - (k - 1)^{n + 1}}{k - 1} = k^n - (k - 1)^n$ cases.

Comment: I'd like to ask you kindly how you obtain that $$\sum_{i=1}^n k^{n - i}(k - 1)^{i - 1} = \frac{\frac{k^{n + 1} - (k - 1)^{n + 1}}{k - (k - 1)} - k^n}{k - 1}$$

Comment: @Chess Glad that you asked. First factor out the $(k - 1)^{-1}$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n k^{n-i}(k-1)^i = \left(\sum_{i=0}^n k^{n-i}(k-1)^i\right) - k^n$. The first sum is in the form of $\sum_{i=0}^n a^i b^{n-i} = \frac{a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}}{a-b}$.

Comment: All clear, thank you very much!

Comment: Just a curiosity... Do you have any reference on where to find formulas like $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}a^ib^{n-i}=\frac{a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}}{a-b}$$

Comment: @chess umm not any reference it’s just a variation on $\sum a^i$

Comment: Yeah, it's clear... I'd like ask kindly if there is in general a reference in which I can find some combinatorical formulas that involve for example binomial coeffincients and so on...